# Flex wrap items at larger breakpoint, while overflow scrolling at smallest

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

I am trying to accommodate a responsive design that has horizontally-scrolling rows of a varying number of items at the mobile breakpoint, but that dumps all items into one big wrapping row on desktop (aligned left, no overflow or scrolling). I've got mobile working as I intend, but am struggling with desktop.

```
/*SCSS*/
$spacer: 8px;
$border: 1px solid #c3c1c0;

.category-flex-outer-container {
  margin: ($spacer*2) (-$spacer*4) ($spacer*2) (-$spacer*4);

    h3 {
      margin: $spacer*2 $spacer*4;
      position: absolute;
      }
}

/* testing only */
.category-flex-item {
  border: $border;
  display: flex;
  margin: $spacer*2;
  padding: $spacer*2;
  text-align: center;
  width: 220px;
}

/* END testing only */

.category-flex-inner-container {
  background: #fff;
  padding: $spacer*6 $spacer*2 $spacer*2;
  
  /* testing only */
  &.one {
    .category-flex-item {
      background: #d14124;
    }
  }

  &.two {
    .category-flex-item {
      background: #44a705;
    }
  }

  &.three {
    .category-flex-item {
      background: #008eaa;
    }
  }

  &.four {
    .category-flex-item {
      background: #ebbc4e;
    }
  }
  
  /* END testing only */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .category-flex-inner-container {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  
  .category-flex-outer-container {
    overflow: scroll;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .category-flex-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .category-flex-outer-container {
    width: 20%;
    
    h3 {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  .category-flex-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

<!--HTML-->
<div class="category-flex-wrapper">
          <div class="category-flex-outer-container">
            <h3>Heading 1</h3>
              <div class="category-flex-inner-container one">   
                <div class="category-flex-item">
                 1
                </div>
                <div class="category-flex-item">
                 2
                </div>
                <div class="category-flex-item">
                 3
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>            
          <div class="category-flex-outer-container">
            <h3>Heading 2</h3>
            <div class="category-flex-inner-container two">
              <div class="category-flex-item">
               4
          </div>
          <div class="category-flex-item">
            5
          </div>
          <div class="category-flex-item">
            6
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>            
      <div class="category-flex-outer-container">
        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
        <div class="category-flex-inner-container three">
          <div class="category-flex-item">
            7
          </div>
          <div class="category-flex-item">
            8
          </div>
          <div class="category-flex-item">
            9
          </div>
          <div class="category-flex-item">
            10
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>            
      <div class="category-flex-outer-container">
        <h3>Heading 4</h3>
        <div class="category-flex-inner-container four">
          <div class="category-flex-item">
            11
          </div>
          <div class="category-flex-item">
            12
          </div>
          <div class="category-flex-item">
            13
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Razzle/5hmdLgba/19/

[Desired desktop design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhwpH.png)

Comment: I don't get much of the logic in this case on why you would want the `10` to be below `3` instead of putting it above `11` and push `13` down below `3`. You would most likely need to use js to add any "left-over" per column (when over 3 items) to the next "set" (after the first 12 items from 4 different categories)

Comment: Yeah, fair point re: the numbers. That was more for me to understand the flex direction. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Would you need js to put 10 above 11 and push 13 down below 3?

Comment: yes and no, it depends on your logic and what you are wanting to achieve here. Is there a reason you want it to go from top to bottom up to 3 rows before you fill the next set of 3 by 4 instead of just filling the page left to right, row by row?

Comment: Nope, I just want it to fill the page left to right, row by row.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to fill ltr and row by row, then this should do it.

```css
.text-small{
  font-size:14px;
}
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;

  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.flex-item{
  width: 100%;
}    
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
  <li class="flex-item">9</li>
  <li class="flex-item">10 <p class="text-small">
  Extend Entire Row to the same max height
  </p></li>
  <li class="flex-item">11</li>
  <li class="flex-item">12</li>
  <li class="flex-item">13</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the items to be broken up by rows that overflow at the mobile breakpoint.